# Firebase functions deploy results in "Error in the build environment"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

When I try to deploy functions with the `firebase-tools cli` I always receive a Deployment error for every function. The output looks like this:

```
!  functions[import]: Deployment error.
Error in the build environment
```

I have tried to deploy in different ways:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

and

```
firebase deploy --only functions:[function-name]
```

Both result in a Deployment error. The packaged functions folder gets upload successfully.
Is there any way to update my current functions?

Comment: If you ever see an error during deployment that's not helpful, be sure to examine the firebase-debug.log file that's left behind, or run again with with debug enabled `firebase deploy --debug`.  That may contain helpful information to share.

Comment: I've tried that, but I couldn't find any relevant information on what caused the error. I've submitted an issue on the firebase-tools repository. There you can find my firebase-debug.log - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/630

Comment: Please contact Firebase support with as much information about your project as you can.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Have tried that as well ;). I'll just wait out their response. Thanks Doug!

Answer (score 0):

I did as @Jirawatee has suggested but was then having some issues with my node version.
So I changed my version of node to V8 and added the engine key my package.json. then removed my node modules, reinstalled them and tried the deploy again

so:

1.) install updates

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

2.) change your global node version to 8 *I personally use Nodist for Windows to manage my node version*

3.) add engine to `package.json`

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
```

4.) remove and reinstall node modules

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

5.) finally, run your firebase build / deploy script

Answer (score -1):

I meet this problem too and I fix it by command lines below.

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Hope it will help :)